# How to solve limitations of 32-bit PHP in drupal 8

Tags: 8, installation

I am unable to complete the setup of Drupal 8. When I get to the third step then the error below will be displayed stating:

> "You are running on a system where PHP is compiled or limited to using
>   32-bit integers. This will limit the range of dates and timestamps to
>   the years 1901-2038. Read about the limitations of 32-bit PHP."

I am using a 32-bit windows 7 system. How can I resolve this issue?

[image: Drupal 8.5.3 Setup Error with 32-bit PHP]

Comment: Isn't there a "continue anyway" link or something at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Re @Clive's comment, there is an issue to make this clearer.

Answer (score 5):

There is a "continue anyway" link at the bottom. I've had the same problem, but for the install process this is only a warning, and will not prevent you from using Drupal 8.

Also, credit to Clive for mentioning this first.

Comment: I did step "continue anyway" from providing your information. I will see the final step on the installation. When I click on "View your existing site" then after my page will be blank and display some error.

Comment: Error display like: **The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.</br></br><em class="placeholder">Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException</em>:  in <em class="placeholder">Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\PathProcessorFront-&gt;processInbound()</em> (line <em class="placeholder">43</em> of <em class="placeholder">core\lib\Drupal\Core\PathProcessor\PathProcessorFront.php</em>)**

Comment: That is going to be a separate issue. Look at your error logs for your server (you might have a missing PHP library or something set incorrectly), and if need be, wipe your database and start the installation over.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question on how to "solve" the error or indeed the underlying issue - you cannot.

Due to the maximum size of a signed 32-bit integer the latest time/date a 32-bit integer can represent is [03:14:07 UTC on Tuesday, 19th January 2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) the only solution available is to use 64-bit software versions or work around the issue in other ways some ideas for how to resolve the issue are given in an answer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012589/php-mysql-year-2038-bug-what-is-it-how-to-solve-it)

Comment: This issue come up more for people who need timestamps in the past, before 1901.